# Self-resolved narrow-scope Questions need to close permanently

Tags: feature-request

A question like **[THIS](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/110074/do-action-init-in-wp-settings-php-breaks-my-website-all-plugins-and-themes)** is not irrelevant no unwelcoming too. But when the Question-asker himself/herself solved the problem and such a condition can never happen to anybody. And if happen, he/she can solve the problem similarly. So the scope of such question is a bit narrower to some specific conditions.

So, whether by Commenting or by Answering the Question/Problem is resolved.

I think such a Question can be CLOSED forever.

But we don't want to prevent spreading knowledge. So I'd recommend to pose a notice there like:

> **CLOSED: THE QUESTION OR PROBLEM IS MARKED WITH NARROW SCOPE**
>   The Question or Problem is specific to some incidental conditions and might not happen without such a condition again to anybody. So the question is closed for further answer.
>   But till, if you want to put an excellent Solution/Answer to the question, **[Propose an Answer](http://answer-this-question-specially.stackexchange.com#)** to the Question. A moderator will review your answer and then can be published.

The language can be whatever the community decides. The Special Answer given by someone will now be in a Queue to the Administrators, Moderators, or with certain Reputation users. After their approval as a correct/more relevant answer the Answer will be published.

Answer (score 1):

When the problem is a configuration error, it is covered by too localized:

> Questions that are too localized (such as syntax errors, code with restricted access, hacked sites, hosting or support issues) are not in scope. See how do I ask a good question?

The solution cannot help future visitors, because they:

- will probably never find this question
- don’t know what exactly has to be changed

So vote to close or flag it for moderator attention.

Oh, and closed questions cannot get answers, so you suggestion is technically impossible.

Answer (score 0):

First, we have `too localized` as *close reason*.

Then I'm not even sure if the problem is `too localized`, as it's *so far* completely unclear what causes the problem. Currently the question teaches later users how to

- Backtrace and Debug failing WP Cron API "jobs"/callbacks

Later on the question might evolve to something completely different, so please at least give it a chance to see if it is *too localized*.